# Trouble with while true and if function in python

Tags: python

The question is "Ask user to enter age, Check if age entered is > 0. if age less than 12 ticket price is 12 dollars otherwise the ticket price is 18 dollars"

```
def main() :
    n = int(input("Insert your age : ")) #asking for users age
    while True : # checking if users age is more than 0
        if n > 0 :
            break
    return n
    if price_checker(n) :
        print("Price is 12 dollars")
    else :
        print("Price is 18 dollars")
    
def price_checker(x) :
    if x < 12 :
        return True
    else :
        return False
    
main()
```

When i print it the only code executed was "insert your age : " i've tried a few ways to fix it but it just lead to more confusion

Comment: If the age is negative it's impossible to change `n` so the loop will run forever, and the rest of the program will never start

Comment: Why do you have `return n` in the middle of the function?  Everything after it can't run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the number is less than or equal to 0 instead of a while loop

```py
def main() :
    n = int(input("Insert your age : ")) #asking for users age
    if n <= 0:
        print("Please enter an age greater than 0")
    elif price_checker(n) :
        print("Price is 12 dollars")
    else :
        print("Price is 18 dollars")
    
def price_checker(x) :
    if x < 12 :
        return True
    else :
        return False
    
main()
```